# How can i get the current row index at the Prerender event of the Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, prerender

I would like to get the index of the current row at the PreRender event.
How can i do it?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.PreRender
Dim idx as integer =...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx) event does not relate to any specific row in the GridView control (like the RowDataBound for example). As such there is no current row to retrieve.

The [PreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx) event can be used perform any updates before the server control is rendered to the page.

What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Oups! A lot of beer i guess, I will use the RowDataBound instead.